# Analytic intersection between two cubic expressions

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, symbolic-math

I am solving the analytic intersection of 2 cubic curves, whose parameters are defined in two separate functions in the below code.

By plotting the curves, it can be easily seen that there is an intersection:

[image]

zoomed version:

[image]

However, the `sym.solve` is not finding the intersection, i.e. when asking for `print 'sol_ H_I(P) - H_II(P)  =', sol`, no result is returned:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import sympy as sym


def H_I(P):
   return (-941.254840173) + (0.014460465765)*P + (-9.41529726451e-05)*P**2 + (1.23485231253e-06)*P**3

def H_II(P):
     return (-941.254313412) + (0.014234188877)*P + (-0.00013455013645)*P**2 + (2.58697027372e-06)*P**3

fig = plt.figure()

# Linspace for plotting the curves:
P_lin = np.linspace(-5.0, 12.5, 10000)

# Plotting the curves:
p1, = plt.plot(P_lin, H_I(P_lin), color='black' )
p2, = plt.plot(P_lin, H_II(P_lin), color='blue' )

# Labels:
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('15')
plt.legend((p1, p2), ("Curve 1", "Curve 2"), prop=fontP)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.savefig('2_curves.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
plt.close()

# Solving the intersection:
P = sym.symbols('P', real=True)

sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
print 'sol_ H_I(P) - H_II(P)  =', sol
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

is your assumption on the solution being real combined with sympys bad judgement about numerical uncertainty.
If you take out the assignment, you end up with the following code:

```
import sympy as sym

def H_I(P):
   return (-941.254840173) + (0.014460465765)*P + (-9.41529726451e-05)*P**2 + (1.23485231253e-06)*P**3

def H_II(P):
     return (-941.254313412) + (0.014234188877)*P + (-0.00013455013645)*P**2 + (2.58697027372e-06)*P**3

P = sym.symbols('P')
sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
sol = [x.evalf() for x in sol]
print(sol)
```

with the output:

> [-6.32436145176552 + 1.0842021724855e-19*I, 1.79012202335501 +
>   1.0842021724855e-19*I, 34.4111917095165 - 1.35525271560688e-20*I]

You can access the real part of the solution by `sym.re(x)`

### Solution

If you have a specific numeric precision, I think the easiest way to collect your real results is something similar to this piece of code:

```
def is_close(a,b,tol):
    if abs(a-b)<tol: return True
    else: return False

P = sym.symbols('P')
sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
sol = [complex(x.evalf()) for x in sol]
real_solutions = []
for x in sol:
    if is_close(x,x.real,10**(-10)): real_solutions.append(x.real)

print(real_solutions)
```

Because you asked: I use complex as a matter of taste. No need to, depending on your further purpose. No restriction in doing so, though. I write this is_close() as a function for generality reasons. You may want to use this code for other polynomials or use this function in a different context, so why not write the code in a smart and readable way? The initial purpose however is to tell me if variable *x* and its real part *re(x)* are *the same* up to a certain numerical precision, i.e. the imaginary part is negligible. You *should* also check for negligible real parts, which I left out.

### Edit

Small imaginary parts are usually remnants of subtractions on complex numbers that arise somewhere in the solving process. Being treated as exact, sympy does *not erase* them. evalf() gives you a numerical evaluation or approximation of the exact solution. *It is not about better accuracy*. Consider for example:

```
import sympy as sym

def square(P):
    return P**2-2

P = sym.symbols('P')
sol2 = sym.solve(square(P),P)
print(sol2)
```

This code prints:

> [-sqrt(2), sqrt(2)]

and not a float number as you might have expected. The solution is exact and perfectly accurate. However, it is, in my opinion, not suited for further calculations. That's why I use evalf() on every sympy result. If you use the numerical evaluation on all results in this example, the output becomes:

> [-1.41421356237310, 1.41421356237310]

Why is it not suitable for further calculations you may ask? Remember your first code. The first root sympy found was

> -6.32436145176552 + 0.e-19*I

Huh, the imaginary part is zero, nice. However, if you print `sym.im(x) == 0`, the output is **False**. Computers and the statement 'exact' are sensitive combinations. Be careful there.

### Solution 2

If you want to get rid of only the small imaginary part without really imposing an explicit numerical accuracy, you can just use the keyword `.evalf(chop = True)` inside the numerical evaluation. This effectively neglects unnecessarily small numbers and would in your original code just cut off the imaginary part. Considering you are even fine with just ignoring any imaginary parts as you stated in your answer, this is probably the best solution for you. For completeness reasons, here is the corresponding code

```
P = sym.symbols('P')
sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
sol = [x.evalf(chop=True) for x in sol]
```

**But** be aware that this is not really so different from my first approach, if one would also implement the "cut off" for the real part. The difference however is: *you don't have any idea about the accuracy this imposes*. 
If you never work with any other polynomials, it may be fine. The following code should illuminate the problem:

```
def H_0(P):
    return P**2 - 10**(-40)

P = sym.symbols('P')
sol = sym.solve(H_0(P) , P)
sol_full = [x.evalf() for x in sol]
sol_chop = [x.evalf(chop=True) for x in sol]
print(sol_full)
print(sol_chop)
```

Even though your roots are perfectly fine and still exact after using evalf(), they are chopped off because they are too small. This is why I would advise to with the simplest, most general solution all the time. After that, look at your polynomials and become aware of the numerical precision needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. `sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)` returns `-6.32436145176552 + 0.e-19*I ` and the other 2 roots. However, `[x.evalf() for x in sol]` returns `-6.32436145176552 + 1.0842021724855e-19*I` What is `evalf()` doing on `0.e-19*I` so that it is converted to `1.0842021724855e-19*I` ?

Comment: @DavidC. Glad I could help. I added some more information on this as an edit in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated answer :). I have been thinking quite a lot on this, and on alternative solutions. I apologise for the delay, but it has taken me several days of thinking :) Please find below my suggestions on your strategy. I am very happy to discuss. Sorry if I have misunderstood some approaches in your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first result:

```
 sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
 print 'sol_ H_I(P) - H_II(P)  =', sol
```

which prints the following:

> [-6.32436145176552 + 0.e-19*I, 1.79012202335501 + 0.e-19*I, 34.4111917095165 - 0.e-20*I]

I totally agree with your `evalf()` strategy, because it enables better precision:

```
 evalf_result = [x.evalf() for x in sol]
 print '[x.evalf() for x in sol] = ', evalf_result
```

which yields:

> [-6.32436145176552 + 1.0842021724855e-19*I, 1.79012202335501 + 1.0842021724855e-19*I, 34.4111917095165 - 1.35525271560688e-20*I]

Your solution implies working over the `complex` python's built in function, which transforms the above result into a nicer tuple-ish result, in which the "I" symbols are nicely replaced by "j":

```
 complex_evalf_result = complex(x.evalf()) for x in sol
 print 'complex(x.evalf()) for x in sol = ', complex_evalf_result
```

which yields the following:

> [(-6.324361451765517+1.0842021724855044e-19j), (1.7901220233550066+1.0842021724855044e-19j), (34.41119170951654-1.3552527156068805e-20j)]

Since `type(complex_evalf_result)` returns `complex`, it happens that you can now use the `complex_evalf_result.real` strategy to obtain the real part of each `x` in `complex_evalf_result`. This has been your strategy, and I agree.

Once that `evalf` and `complex` functions have been applied, then you now implement a `is_close` function approach, which I have found very interesting:

"If the abs difference between the real part and the complex part are less than 10E-10, then discard the complex part."

This is generally true for a case where the complex part is smaller than 10E-10. For example, for

> [(-6.324361451765517+1.0842021724855044e-19j), (1.7901220233550066+1.0842021724855044e-19j), (34.41119170951654-1.3552527156068805e-20j)]

It happens that:

`abs(-6.324361451765517+1.0842021724855044e-19j - (-6.324361451765517)) =
1.0842021724855044e-19`,

which is always less than 10E-10.

Your function is essentially discarding the complex part (please forgive me if there is also another application to this function and I am a bit fool to not understand it).

So, why not perhaps use this simpler solution?

```
 import numpy as np
 import sympy as sym
 from sympy.functions import re

 # Crude intersection:
 sol = sym.solve(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
 print 'sol_ H_I(P) - H_II(P)  =', sol

 print """

 """
 # Use of evalf to obtain better precision:
 evalf_result = [x.evalf() for x in sol]
 print '[x.evalf() for x in sol] = ', evalf_result

 print """

 """
 # Now, let's grab the real part of the evalf_result:
 real_roots = []
 for x in evalf_result:
   each_real_root = re(x)
   real_roots.append(each_real_root)

 print 'real_roots = ', real_roots
```

This directly prints:

> real_roots =  [-6.32436145176552, 1.79012202335501, 34.4111917095165]

By following this strategy, it happens that:

1) there is no need to call the python's `complex` built-in strategy. Once the `evalf` function has done the job, the real part can be extracted simply by `re(x)`.

2) there is no need to pass our intersection results over a `is_close` function just to discard the complex part.

Please tell me if there is something that I am misunderstanding, or something that you do not quite agree with - I am very happy to discuss :) All your help has been awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a forum. The posts in the answer field are supposed to directly answer the questions, not to discuss other answers. If you wish to open a discussion with the user Banana, please find another venue, such as [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings there, so I updated my answer yet again (completely). Most of your questions have the simple answer: Generality. I didn't write my answer to work just for the 2 polynomials you mentioned, but for basically all. 

I suggest you read my updated version over again, but I agree with @CrazyIvan, so if there are any open questions left, I'm happy to chat with you.

Answer (score 0):

To find the roots of a polynomial, use the dedicated method [roots](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyroots.roots) instead of generic `solve`.

```
sol = sym.roots(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P)
```

This returns the roots as a dictionary with multiplicities,
`{-6.32436145176552: 1, 1.79012202335501: 1, 34.4111917095165: 1}`

It is often more convenient to get a list of roots instead (multiple roots, if any, will be repeated):

```
sol = sym.roots(H_I(P) - H_II(P) , P, multiple=True)
```

returns `[-6.32436145176552, 1.79012202335501, 34.4111917095165]`

---

If this equation was not a polynomial, I'd recommend using SciPy's solvers like `fsolve` instead of SymPy.  SymPy is not the right tool to find the numeric solution of an equation full of floating point coefficients. It's designed to do symbolic math, and symbolic math and floating point numbers don't mix well.